# How to print multiple lists having a common name but numbered differently using for-loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Is there a correct syntax to print multiple lists which have a common part in their name but differ by a number?

For example, I have two lists here, test1 and test2, and I want the full lists to be printed. I will have multiple lists in the actual code which I why I wanted to use the for-loop.

```
test1 = [3,4,4,4]
test2 = [7,8,8,8]
for i in range(1,3):
 print("test"+ str(i))
```

Desired output -

```
[3,4,4,4]
[7,8,8,8]
```

Comment: Why would you need something like that? Why not just `print(test1)` and `print(test2)`. `for loop` with `range` seems unnecessary here since you are not doing anything with the iterated value.

Comment: I have simplified the code that I am asking here. I will be working with the iterated values and quite a few lists.

Comment: print(locals()["test"+ str(i)])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `eval()`

```
test1 = [3, 4, 4, 4]
test2 = [7, 8, 8, 8]
for i in range(1, 3):
    print(eval(f'test{i}'))
```

Or just keep list of the lists instead

```
tests = [test1, test2, ...]
for t in tests:
    print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible.

```
test1 = [3, 4, 4, 4]
test2 = [7, 8, 8, 8]
for i in range(1, 3):
    print(globals().get('test' + str(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to obtain the dict of local or global variables and then print them out.

```
test1 = 123
test2 = 512

for i in range(1, 3):
    print(locals()["test"+str(i)])

123
512
```

No need for `eval`, `get` or `getattr`. Just simple indexing into dict.